# HTML canvas dynamic masking

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, masking

Simply put, I'm drawing a red line across the screen on an HTML canvas and I would like a moving white circle to only be visible on the current portion of the line that it's touching. I read a lot about canvas masking but I haven't run into a similar situation to use as a reference. The entire circle should never be visible, only the portion of it that's covering the line or lines if there happen to be more than one.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: @CountingStacks : Let me give you some advice to improve your question : 1) mention the readings you did, or the conclusions of your readings, we might all benefit from it 2) show all the attempts you did to solve the issue, best done with some code + a jsbin. (starter : jsbin.com/demusopajane/2/edit?js,console,output). 3) underline the issue. Best regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm glad to hear you're learning about the more advanced html Canvas capabilities!

I suggest you next read about `context.globalCompositeOperation`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing

Compositing allows you to manipulate how new drawings are drawn relative to existing drawings.

In particular, the `source-atop` compositing mode should be helpful in your situation because new drawings (your circle) will only appear where it intersects existing drawings (your line).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Why the downvote?  I believe my post contributes useful information to the conversation.

Comment: I find it sad that you laugh (and presumably enjoy) insulting and hurting people with your comments. Such an attitude makes Stackoverflow a less welcoming and enjoyable place to visit.

Comment: I apologize that I wasn't on here sooner to see your response. This was exactly what I needed. My reputation does not allow me to vote you up but I would if I could! 'source-atop' did just what I wanted.